# ListView OnItemClickListener is not listening

Tags: android, android-listview

I checked all the previous questions regarding this issue , but none of them are helpfull to me .

My listview is not responding  , i tried changing this
**list.setOnItemClickListener(new ContactsListItemClickListener(this));**

to

**list.setOnItemClickListener(this);**

by making my PrioritiseContacts activity just imeplement OnItemClickListener , but then too its not working .

The activity is successfully running , but i am unable to listen for listclick events.

How to correct this?

Here is my class :

```
public class PrioritiseContacts extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ListView list;
    // list of contacts with name
    private List<Contacts> contactsList;
    private Controller controll;
    private ContactListAdapters adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_contacts);

        controll = new Controller();
        contactsList = controll.fetchContacts(this);

        // call the adapter to set the list view layout
        adapter = new ContactListAdapters(contactsList, this);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_contacts);
        // set the adapter to list
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new ContactsListItemClickListener(this));

        // inflate the list of contact
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", 1000).show();

    }

    class ContactsListItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
        private Context c;

        public ContactsListItemClickListener(
                PrioritiseContacts prioritiseContacts) {
            this.c = prioritiseContacts;

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Clicked", 1500).show();
            System.out.print("clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

My select_contacts xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" 
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_select_contacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Choose Contacts"
        android:textColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </TextView>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_contacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my adapter's getview() :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        // layout infklater to inflate the post list view
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_view, null);
        }

        Contacts c = contactList.get(position);

        // set text views in contact lists
        // Typeface custom_font =
        // Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/calibril.ttf");
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_contact_name);
        // date.setTypeface(custom_font);
        name.setText(c.getName());

        TextView number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
        // title.setTypeface(custom_font);
        number.setText(c.getPhone());

        ImageView contact_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_single_contact);
        // hut.setTypeface(custom_font);
        if(c.getContactImage() != null)
        contact_image.setImageBitmap(c.getContactImage());
        else
            contact_image.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture_2));


        return view;
    }
```

My contacts_list_view xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rl_post_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_single_contact"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:padding="2dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.87"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_contact_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:text="Contact Name"
                android:textColor="#fdfbfb"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <View style="@style/Divider" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="this is number"
                android:textColor="#fdfbfb"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_contact"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:padding="2dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any row item of list contains `focusable` or `clickable` view then `OnItemClickListener` won't work such as for checkbox or button etc in the row item.There are two solution:

**1**. row item must be having param like `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    // your other widgets here

</LinearLayout>
```

**2.** Set given two attributes to false
like

```
 android:focusable="false"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

For example if there is any checkbox or button or image in the row item then

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/fav_check_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

Comment: check it now , i added it at he end

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"  add this in the linear layout of contact_list_view

Comment: thank you , it worked . Why this happened , can you pls explain me ?

Comment: i am updating my answer.I will give reason